# Is Git Access rights reporting safe?

Tags: git, gitolite

I think if a team member's local repo is leaked , the "access rights reporting" may leak the server's git version and other repos' name. Is it true? Could I disable the "access rights reporting"?

[Access rights reporting](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Gitolite)

> Access rights reporting: Another convenient feature is what happens
>   when you try and just ssh to the server. Gitolite shows you what repos
>   you have access to, and what that access may be. Here’s an example:
>
> ```
> hello scott, this is git@git running gitolite3 v3.01-18-g9609868 on git 1.7.4.4
>
>      R     anu-wsd
>      R     entrans
>      R  W  git-notes
>      R  W  gitolite
>      R  W  gitolite-admin
>      R     indic_web_input
>      R     shreelipi_converter
> ```

If try to login the server use "ssh git@git", will also get this result.

Comment: `hello scott` ... doesn't this imply that someone already logged in, in which case sensitive information isn't just being "leaked" out?

Comment: I konw, but you will know all the accessible repos. I may not clone all the accessible repos on the same client, but I would like to use the same SSH key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you will know all the accessible repos

Only scott would know the accessible repos, so no leak here.

> I may not clone all the accessible repos on the same client, but I would like to use the same SSH key

Use the same SSH key on different client is not the best practice, as the private ssh key is no longer "private" (to a user *and* a client), and revoking it would cancel access from *all* clients.
Still, only `scott` would get access to that list of repos from any client, so no leak there either.

> If try to login the server use "ssh git@git", will also get this result.

Any ssh request to a gitolite server *always* use the same account (here git). You are authenticated through your public ssh kays what was registered in the `gitolite-admin/keydir` repo: see "[basic admin](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/basic-admin.html)".

Comment: I mean my own devices, such as my iMac, Mac Pro, Windows. Definitely I am not going to use my private key on other devices. And if you leave for a while, but forget to lock your notebook. Others may test an ssh request on your notebook.

Comment: @ovalpo I understand. The general idea behind this answer still stands though.